# Extract photo from contact

Tags: contacts, photos

This is a friend of mine, Taranaki: (perfect picture timing)

[image: Best contact photo 2016]

I want to extract this photo to a PNG on my device. How do I do that?

Comment: Is the Android rooted?

Comment: @Firelord no, it's not.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to do the following steps:

1. Go to `contacts`
2. `Options > Import/Export`
3. Select `Export to .vcf file`

Now the .vcf backup will be stored in your storage.

1. Open .vcf file in an advanced editor (in pc or phone)
2. Scroll and find the entry of the particular contact.
3. You can find a base64 encrypted code of your contact's photo -copy it.
4. Now open some `online base64 decoder` and paste the code and click decrypt.

You have your photo. Enjoy.

Comment: you can also share the particular contact to, say, your gmail account or bluetooth or ES file explorer (save to storage) .etc. which will extract just that contact as a .vcf file instead of all contacts.

Comment: Or if you are a rooted user, you can find the sqlite database where all the contact info is stored by navigating to `/data/data/com.Android.providers/contacts/databases/contacts.db`

Comment: The VCF only stores a 96x96, which isn't good enough. @AbhishekK Can I access that with ADB?

Comment: @Soren yes, mostly (but not all) contacts apps export `.vcf` with the reduced sized images. Actual images are stored in `/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/files/photos/`, not accessible through `adb` without root.

Comment: Worked for me the solution of base64 encrypted code but its not the regular base64 online web, its base64 image decoder online web, that its not equal... I opened the vcf file with notepad++
I copy the base64 code without the first type codes:
PHOTO;TYPE=PNG;ENCODING=B:
I opened on a base64 image decoder online web: https://base64.guru/converter/decode/image And thats it !! :) Regards.